# How to set colour on a button from colour picker methods?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I generate some buttons in a for loop, each with its own tag. Now I want to tap on a button and open a colour picker and set the colour of the button.

My problem is that when I open the colour picker and choose a color it gets set on a different button. I want to tap on a button and choose the colour for the tapped button only.

The code i am using is:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){ 
    btnphoto=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,(30*i)+110,50,20)];    
    [btnphoto setTitle:@"Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];     
    [btnphoto setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
    [btnphoto addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressPickColor:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
    btnphoto.tag=100 + i;
    [self.view addSubview:btnphoto];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressPickColor:(UIButton*)sender
{   
    btnphoto.tag = sender.tag;
    NSLog(@"Btn photo Tag = %d",sender.tag);
    NEOColorPickerViewController *controller = [[NEOColorPickerViewController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.selectedColor = self.currentColor;
    controller.title = @"Color Picker";
    UINavigationController* navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller]; 
    [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)colorPickerViewController:(NEOColorPickerBaseViewController *)controller didSelectColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
    btnphoto.backgroundColor = color;  /// Important Line
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: please someone answer this question

Comment: leaving a comment on your own question asking for someone to answer it doesn't add any information. We know that you want the question to be answered. Why else would you have asked it in the first place?

Comment: Maybe you can explain / reason a bit around that "important line" in the code.

Comment: because from that line button is having colour..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing would be to have a instance variable/property and set your selected button's tag to it and use that tag to get the correct instance of button...

For example:

In interface file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) int selectedTag;
```

Below is the modified code which gonna help you further

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressPickColor:(UIButton*)sender{   
_selectedTag = sender.tag;
NSLog(@"Btn photo Tag = %d",sender.tag);
NEOColorPickerViewController *controller = [[NEOColorPickerViewController alloc] init];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.selectedColor = self.currentColor;
controller.title = @"Color Picker";
UINavigationController* navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller]; 
[self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
-(void)colorPickerViewController:(NEOColorPickerBaseViewController *)controller didSelectColor:(UIColor *)color {
UIButton *selectedButton = (UIbutton *)[self.view viewWithTag:_selectedTag];
selectedButton.backgroundColor = color;  /// Important Line
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) int _selectedTag ;  I am getting error in this line

Comment: Thanks Prabh.Thank you so much ..You solved my problem./..I was facing this last two days ////