# How to change background colour on dynamic generated buttons?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

For generating buttons I have used For Loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)

{ 

btnphoto=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,(30*i)+110,50,20)];   

[btnphoto setTitle:@"Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   

[btnphoto setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 

[btnphoto addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressPickColor:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

btnphoto.tag=100 + i;

[self.view addSubview:btnphoto];

}
```

How to use TAG or set the tag on object and then change the color.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch case for changing the color of different buttons.

```
switch(i){
case 0:
[btnphoto setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
break;

case1:
[btnphoto setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
break;
...
```

Like this one.

Comment: i have used switch case too ..but it change only the last button colour.

Comment: Probably you forget to put break; on conditions.

Comment: the answer you gave is correct if i have five buttons …But if i don't know how many buttons will be there then???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163811/how-to-set-colour-on-a-button-from-colour-picker-methods    My exact problem is this //If you can please please help me  this .

Comment: Ok in that case you can write something like that 
[UIColor colorWithRed: i green:i blue:i alpha:1] make sure i is less than 255. or you can just modify the values for r g b for different i.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41768/discussion-between-user2754190-and-souvickcse)